# Laravel dependency injection in domain namespace

Tags: php, laravel-4, ioc-container

I am having issues getting dependency injection to work with dependency inversion.  I can call App::make in the constructor, and the dependency inversion works just fine ... it is only when I try to inject it into the constructor that I have issues.

```
ReflectionException Class StationsInterface does not exist
```

A uri that would hit this would be .../stats/station/mogreet/6

The File Stucture:

```
-app

    -controllers
        *StatsController

-Dashboard

    -Datasync

        -Interfaces
            *DatasyncInterface
            *MogreetDatasyncInterface

        -Services
            *MogreetDatasync

        *BackendServiceProvider
        *DatasyncBase

    -Repositories

        -Interfaces
            *CredentialsInterface
            *StationsInterface

        -Stations
            *DbCredentials
            *DbStations
            *FileCredentials

        -Stats

        *BackendServiceProvider
        *DbRepositoryBase
```

The relevant code blocks are as follows:

Service Provider:

```
<?php namespace Dashboard\Repositories;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BackendServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {

        // Service Providers located in Stats directory
        $this->app->bind('StatsDailyInterface', 'Dashboard\Repositories\Stats\DbStatsDaily');
        //$this->app->bind('StatsMonthlyRepository', 'Dashboard\Repositories\Stats\DbStatsMonthly');
        //$this->app->bind('StatsYearlyRepository', 'Dashboard\Repositories\Stats\DbStatsYearly');

        // Service Providers located in Stations directory
        $this->app->bind('CredentialsInterface', 'Dashboard\Repositories\Stations\FileCredentials');
        $this->app->bind('StationsInterface', 'Dashboard\Repositories\Stations\DbStations');

    }

}
```

Controller: Note that in the constructor of this I am using App::make instead of Injecting the Dependency.  If I inject the dependency I get a class resolution error exactly like I do in the DatasyncBase class.

```
<?php

use Dashboard\ConrollerFacades\Facades\Services;

class StatsController extends BaseController {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Stats Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Pull and display stats for station, market, or corporate views
    |
    |   
    |
    */

    private $StationModel;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->StationModel = App::make('StationsInterface');
    }

    /**
    * Pulls stats for an individual station
    *
    * @param string $service of station
    * @param integer $id of station
    * 
    * @return void
    */
    public function station( $service, $stationId ) {

        $this->Service = $this->serviceSelector($service);

        if(!$this->Service) throw new Exception('Unknown Service Selected', 1);

        $this->Service->init($stationId);

        exit();

    }

    /**
    * Pulls stats for a Market
    *
    * @param integer $id of market
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function market( $service, $marketId ) {

        $this->Service = $this->serviceSelector($service);

        if(!$this->Service) throw new Exception('Unknown Service Selected', 1);

        foreach($StationModel->getStationIdsByMarket($marketId) as $station) {
            $this->Service->init($station);
        } 

        exit();

    }

    /**
    * Pulls stats for Corporate (all stations)
    * 
    * @return void
    */
    public function corporate( $service ) {

        $this->Service = $this->serviceSelector($service);

        if(!$this->Service) throw new Exception('Unknown Service Selected', 1);

        foreach($StationModel->getAllStationIds() as $station) {
            $this->Service->init($station);
        }

        exit();

    }

    private function serviceSelector($service) {

        switch(strtolower($service)) {
            case 'brightcove': return App::make('BrightCoveDatasyncInterface'); break;
            case 'facebook': return App::make('FacebookDatasyncInterface'); break;
            case 'googleanalytics': return App::make('GoogleAnalyticsDatasyncInterface'); break;
            case 'liquidcompass': return App::make('LiquidCompassDatasyncInterface'); break;
            case 'mogreet': return App::make('MogreetDatasyncInterface'); break;
            case 'twitter': return App::make('TwitterDatasyncInterface'); break;
            default: return false; break;
        }

    }

}
```

**The constructor of this class is where the dependency injection issue is occurring.**
DatasyncBase:  This class is never directly instantiated, it is inherited by a service class like MogreetDatasync.  Moving the constructor to the MogreetDatasync class for testing does not resolve the issue.

```
<?php namespace Dashboard\Datasync;

use Dashboard\Repositories\Interfaces\StationsInterface;
use Dashboard\Repositories\Interfaces\CredentialsInterface;

class DatasyncBase {

    protected $Station;
    protected $Credentials;

    protected $results;

    protected $stats;

    public function __construct(StationsInterface $Station , CredentialsInterface $Credentials) {
        $this->Station = $Station;
        $this->Credentials = $Credentials;
        $this->stats = array();
    }

    public function __destruct() {

        unset($this->results);
        unset($this->stats);

    }

    public function init() {}

    protected function fetch($uri = null, $post_fields = null) {

        $cURL = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
        curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
        $this->results = curl_exec($cURL);
        curl_close($cURL); 

    }

}
```

A Datasync Service:

```
<?php namespace Dashboard\Datasync\Services;

use Dashboard\Datasync\DatasyncBase;
use Dashboard\Datasync\Interfaces\MogreetDatasyncInterface;

class MogreetDatasync extends DatasyncBase implements MogreetDatasyncInterface {

    public function init($stationId) {}
    protected function uri() {}
    protected function parse() {}
    protected function write() {}

}
```

Comment: Where are you instantiating the DatasyncBase class? Do you realize you have to App::make() if you want laravel to inject the dependencies from the IOC container?

Comment: The DatasyncBase class is just a parent of Datasync, so it is instantiated through inheritence of MogreetDatasync.  I was not aware that you have to App::make() to inject dependencies, most of the examples I have only use bind.  I will start looking into that approach, but if you have a good example/tutorial you can point me to, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Automatic injection from the type hint is something Laravel does and not something that PHP does. The reason you can inject from your controllers constructor is because it's instantiated with Laravel's IOC container's build() method. Take a look at that class, and you will get a better understanding of what's going on. I even believe Laracasts has a screencast about it :)

Comment: I am trying to use Dependency Inversion with Dependency Injection.  Needing to use App::make makes since for the IOC container to be able to resolve the binding.  I am still having trouble getting the Dependency Inversion to work.  I will update the question to reflect the code changes that have been made, as well as the directory structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is closures for the ServiceDatasyncInterfaces.  Previously I was defining the bindings like this:

```
$this->app->bind('MogreetDatasyncInterface', 'Dashboard\Datasync\Services\MogreetDatasync');
```

This however does NOT allow the IoC to "recursively" inject the Inversion Dependencies, you must use App::make('InversionInterface') for IoC to actually resolve this correctly.

```
<?php namespace Dashboard\Datasync;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use Dashboard\Datasync\Services\BrightCoveDatasync;
use Dashboard\Datasync\Services\FacebookDatasync;
use Dashboard\Datasync\Services\GoogleAnalyticsDatasync;
use Dashboard\Datasync\Services\LiquidCompassDatasync;
use Dashboard\Datasync\Services\MogreetDatasync;
use Dashboard\Datasync\Services\TwitterDatasync;

class BackendServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {

        $this->app->bind('BrightCoveDatasyncInterface', function() { return new BrightCoveDatasync( $this->app->make('StationsInterface'), $this->app->make('CredentialsInterface') ); });
        $this->app->bind('FacebookDatasyncInterface', function() { return new FacebookDatasync( $this->app->make('StationsInterface'), $this->app->make('CredentialsInterface') ); });
        $this->app->bind('GoogleAnalyticsDatasyncInterface', function() { return new GoogleAnalyticsDatasync( $this->app->make('StationsInterface'), $this->app->make('CredentialsInterface') ); });
        $this->app->bind('LiquidCompassDatasyncInterface', function() { return new LiquidCompassDatasync( $this->app->make('StationsInterface'), $this->app->make('CredentialsInterface') ); });
        $this->app->bind('MogreetDatasyncInterface', function() { return new MogreetDatasync( $this->app->make('StationsInterface'), $this->app->make('CredentialsInterface') ); });
        $this->app->bind('TwitterDatasyncInterface', function() { return new TwitterDatasync( $this->app->make('StationsInterface'), $this->app->make('CredentialsInterface') ); });

    }

}
```

This is a rather minor issue, but you will need to use the correct interface in the file containing the class that is being injected.  My DatasyncBase file now looks like this:

```
<?php namespace Dashboard\Datasync;

use Dashboard\Repositories\Interfaces\StationsInterface;
use Dashboard\Repositories\Interfaces\CredentialsInterface;

class DatasyncBase {

    protected $Station;
    protected $Credentials;

    protected $results;

    protected $stats;

    public function __construct(StationsInterface $Station, CredentialsInterface $Credentials) {
        $this->Station = $Station;
        $this->Credentials = $Credentials;
        $this->stats = array();
    }

    public function __destruct() {

        unset($this->results);
        unset($this->stats);

    }

    public function init() {}

    protected function fetch($uri, $post_fields = '') {

        $cURL = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
        curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
        $this->results = curl_exec($cURL);
        curl_close($cURL); 

    }

}
```

You can find more on ServiceProvider's here:
https://laracasts.com/lessons/service-providers-decoded